# Total Gauss curvature

Tags: integration, differential-geometry

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a connex, compact $2$ - dimensional submanifold. Assume that the Gauss application $N$ is one to one (injective map) and that the Gauss curvature $K$ satisfies $K(p) \neq 0$ for all $p \in S$. We know that : 
$$\int_S K(p) dp = 4 \pi $$

> Is the conclusion still the same if we do not assume $K(p) \neq 0$ for all $p \in S$ ?

If you know how to answer this question please tell me !

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you know the total curvature is $4\pi$ in your situation? (I'm not disputing the fact, just trying to gauge why you're asking the question.)

Comment: The change of variable $q=N (p)$ is a diffeomorphism and the theorem of change of variable can be applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the conclusion still holds: Under the stated assumptions, the Gauss map $N:S \to S^{2}$ is a smooth homeomorphism. (The inverse map isn't smooth at the images of points with $K = 0$.) Consequently you can still run the change of variables argument, i.e., can use $N$ to pull back the area form $dA$ of $S^{2}$:
$$
4\pi = \int_{S^{2}} dA
  = \int_{S} N^{*} dA
  = \int_{S} K(p)\, dp.
$$

In fact, you don't even need $N$ to be injective; you can get by if $N$ has degree $1$, i.e., $N$ maps the fundamental ($2$-dimensional homology) class of $S$ to the fundamental class of $S^{2}$. Thus, for example, $S$ could be a "lozenge" comprising a cylinder with hemispherical end caps (or smoothed end caps, so that $K$ is continuous).

Alternatively, the fact that $N:S \to S^{2}$ is a homeomorphism means you can apply Gauss-Bonnet to $S$, deducing the total curvature is $4\pi$.

Comment: You answered more than I expected :) Your answer is really great !

Comment: hi, Andrew hope is not too late for my questions. Is $dp$ just a short hand notation for the area form over $S$? I am a bit confused by the fact that $p$ is also a point of $S$. Then one thing that I don't understand is why we can apply the change of variables formula also if $N$ is not a diffeomorphism (i.e. the determinant of the Jacobian is zero somewhere). It makes sense to me considering your point about Gauss Bonnet but maybe it is just my ignorance here. Thanks!!